# (Laravel) Lock Several Rows Only from a Set of Available Data

Tags: laravel, database

I'm having difficulties on implementing this specific scenario.

We are running a ticket system where people can booked specific amount of seat and then we assign the seat number to them. To prevent double booking, we are using lockForUpdate when updating the assigned seat status.

However, our performance got hit during ticket rush because apparently our code lock the entire seat that available instead of only lock the assigned seat. Here is the simple version of our code

```
//start transaction here

//query for the available seat then take 2 seat to be assigned (in this case, user book 2 seats)
$assignedSeat = VenueSeat::available()
            ->where('event_id', "1")
            ->take(2)
            ->lockForUpdate()
            ->get();

//we update the assigned seat status to booked

//finish transaction
```

We are thinking to query the available seat and take the specific amount first, keep the ids, then running another query with that ids to lock and update it (this will guarantee row lock), but I think this approach will still allow double booking during race condition. Is there another approach that I can take for this specific scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The quick resolution to this question.
I think the intended way is to do this like so:

```
DB::transaction(function() {
        $assignedSeat = VenueSeat::available()
            ->where('event_id', "1")
            ->take(2)
            ->lockForUpdate()
            ->get();
});
```

Comment: Hi, this is what our code looks like right now, and it will lock entire seat that available instead of only the assigned one (2 seats)